# Sublime Text 2 Python Issue. Python in Path and can be compiled via cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, cmd, sublimetext2

Hello I am someone new to Python and am trying to get started.

Problem:
I have Sublime Text 2 and am having problems running some simple code.

I have:
Python Installed @ C:\Program Files\Python\Python 278

Work Folder with Code @ C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Learning Python

Code is: ex1.py

I have added Python to my Environment Variables (both User variables and system variables).

My sublime is set for Python.

Here is my code:

> print "Yo"

When I try to build I get:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\Learning Python\\ex1.py', u'-o', u'C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\Learning Python/ex1']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Learning Python]
[path: ...;C:\Program Files\Python\Python 278]
[Finished]
```

I can run python from powershell and cmd.
http://gyazo.com/cfa64a39730b3aefce6daf530a099453

Again I must stress that typing python in my cmd will start the python interpreter

I even changed Python.sublime-build

> "cmd": ["C:\Program Files\Python\Python 278\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
>
> "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
>
> "selector": "source.python"

and

> "cmd": ["C:\Program Files\Python\Python 278\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
>
> "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
>
> "selector": "source.python"

and originally it was

> "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
>
> "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
>
> "selector": "source.python"

Please help. I have spent over 7 hours on this problem and I am sure I just missed something stupid.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: your editor is trying to compile the file, try to find an option to change it so that it will treat the file as a py

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am mega stupid.

I saw this:
http://gyazo.com/6b3d484b8d00831b631bacc73fe6825a

and thought I set my build system to Python.
Nope!

Please Tools->Build System->Python